# how to delay this text fade on with js setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

How can I delay this event (text sliding into frame) using setTimeout?

```
//fadeIn active slide
$($containerClass+' .swiper-slide:nth-child('+ (currentSlide + 1) +')').find('.content').children().each(function(i){
    $(this).delay(i*90).animate({
        'opacity' : 1,
        'padding-top' : 0
    },{ duration: 400, easing: 'easeOutQuad'}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate your exact scenario, so I created a jsfiddle doing what I believe you're asking for.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jmP9b/1/)

Javascript used in fiddle:

```
// Iterate over slides
$.each($(".slide"), function (i, o) {
    // settimeout
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(o).animate({
            left: "+=420"
        }, 400, function () {
            // Do something

        });
    }, i * 1000); // Increment the wait
});
```

Comment: possible to use something like this 
     setTimeout(function () {
    ,3000);
around my existing code?